# VS Code how to combine HTML into .JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I try to create a `React` project in VS Code. When I try to save `index.js` with the HTML tags as below, VS Code breaks my tags and pushes spaces between words and brackets. Can’t find how I can fix it…

```
// this is before I safe the project
ReactDOM.render( <div> Hello World! </div>, document.getElementById('root'))

// this is after I safe the project
ReactDOM.render( < div > Hello World! < /div>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake

Comment: I find) need to switch the language in lower right corner

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Change all `.js` file extensions to `.jsx`.
2. Add file association in user/workspace settings:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  }
```